# C# - Referencing objects in MVC data model

Tags: c#, oop, model-view-controller, reference

I'm building a piece of software using the MVC pattern in C#. The software has a complex data model with a number of classes and creates on runtime lot's of objects of those model classes (controlled by the user). However, the objects of one class (`ParkingGarage`) reference to the objects of the other class (`Car`) - so the `ParkingGarage` objects store references to all `Car` objects (in an Array), which are currently parked in the specific garage.

**Class `Car`**

```
- Property (String) Model
- Property (String) Color
- Property (String) LicensePlate
```

**Class `ParkingGarage`**

```
- Property (String) Name
- Property (String) LocationAddress
- Property (Array) ParkedCars
```

When now storing the `Car` objects in the Array of the `ParkingGarage` objects, can I just have an Array full of `Car` objects or should I store only some kind of an identifier (maybe a property uniqueIdentifier of the `Car` class)?

My current assumption is: If I add `Car` objects to the Array ParkedCars of a `ParkingGarage` object, the array holds only references to the car object, right? Do I get any issues with that?

Comment: It's fine to hold a reference to the collection of objects (Cars), unless there's a specific problem you're facing? In general it's good to do what's simplest and easiest, but of-course if you foresee problems then consider things like lazy loading, filtered collections, etc.

Comment: Usually you would hold the cars in some kind of store, and have a repository to get which ones you need, by model, make, etc.

Comment: My concern was about memory issue, cause there could be plenty of cars object, and in case of one would be destroyes, but the garage object still holds a reference. I'm pretty new to C# and therefore not the expert for memory mgmt. What do you mean with store/repository? Can you pls give me some more details on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave memory management issues to the *runtime* and use the generic List type `List<>` instead of an *array* to hold your data. `List<T>` represents a **growable list of objects** and provides methods such as `Add` and `Remove` which in fact manipulate and array of T under the covers to produce the desired result.

Here's some code you can use as a guideline.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

}

public class ParkingGarage
{
    private List<Car> parkedCars;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LocationAddress { get; set; }

    public List<Car> ParkedCars
    {
        get { return parkedCars; }
    }

    public ParkingGarage()
    {
        parkedCars = new List<Car>();
    }

    public void AddCar(Car car)
    {
        // perform validation
        parkedCars.Add(car);
    }
}
```

To retrieve Cars from your Database you can use the repository pattern:

```
public class CarRepository
{
    public List<Car> FindAll()
    {
        // Code to retrieve all cars 
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        // Retrieve All rows from Cars Table and populate the List
        return cars;           
    }

    public List<Car> FindAllWith(string carModel)
    {
        // Code to retrieve all cars with a particular model
    }

    public List<Car> FindAllWith(int parkingGarageId)
    {
        // Code to retrieve all cars from a particular parking garage
    }

    public void Save(Car car)
    {
       // Code to save car to the database
    }

}
```

Again, Do not worry about memory management, you better focus on creating a good model for your project.

Comment: Thanks, but one more question: Shouldn't there be a property or a public variable for `List<Car>` in the `CarRepository`?

Comment: I see no reason for having a `List<Car>` property inside the repository. Why do you think so?

Comment: How can you then for example find all the car objects with the `FindAll()` method? Shouldn't there be a list which holds all `Car` objects?

Comment: You first create an instance of the repository `CarRepository repo = new CarRepository();` and then populate a List of cars like this: `List<Car> allCars = repo.FindAll();`

Comment: ah ok, got it now. You presumed that I use a database or similar, which holds all car objects and the repository loads them into the `List` - like a mirror of the database

Comment: Yes, in fact the repository pattern is used for far more complex scenarios and you mostly use it with a data mapping tool. But for simple CRUD-like applications a [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) will serve the purpose.